# Vue does not read the API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, vue.js

I'm making an application with Vue that has to read a bee in real time to get some data. The problem is that it can not read the API data.

With this API it works:
[API google](https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=jtQCSKYfXO6tdKHGfComp8TX0tDpy79uPTFLlpsB0JFOc_PM1FHYCNOWpPMbozfXcchiTwZGVF3LYDZhEQhtOEi44PuCjE9Em5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnJ9GRkcRevgjTvo8Dc32iw_BLJPcPfRdVKhJT5HNzQuXEeN3QFwl2n0M6ZmO-h7C6bwVq0tbM60-xIkq8d3Ts1lw4cV1Ks_h9A&lib=MwxUjRcLr2qLlnVOLh12wSNkqcO1Ikdrk)

With what I did not do:
ip my vps = 0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0/api/value

if I try to search for ip using Google Chrome, the data appears. I would like to understand what I am wrong

> Template App.vue

```
 <template>
     <div>
        <h2>{{value}}</h2>
     </div>
   </template>
```

> Script App.vue
>
> Vue.axios.get('IP-MY-VPS/api/value').then((response) => {
>                      this.value = response.data;
>                   })

```
<script>
// Imports
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)


export default {
    data () {
        return {
               value: ''
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        this.loadQuote();
    },
    methods: {
        loadQuote: function(){
            this.value = ' '
            Vue.axios.get('0.0.0.0/api/value').then((response) => {
               this.value = response.data;
            })
        .catch(function (error){
            this.value = 'Error! ' + error;   
        })
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you try view 0.0.0.0/api/value in your browser?

Comment: @Jhecht yeah i see data ip/api/value

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to include **http** or **https protocol**.

Also, when running a local server, **axios** sometimes try to access wrong port.
So please try:

```
Vue.axios.get('http://0.0.0.0:80/api/value').then((response) => {
  this.value = response.data;
})
```

Comment: if you put a debugger in the then block, what is `this`? Sometimes I've had a problem with this scope in Vue, even with arrow functions.